# User input to store in nested lists with int conversion - Python

Tags: python, int, append, nested-lists

I need user input to be stored in a nested list of the form `A = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]]...` and so on, based on a number of nested lists that the user desires. `a, b, c, ...` are integers; so I need to convert the user input from `str` to `int` too. This is what I have got so far:

```
number_of_nested_lists = int(input())
i = 0
data = []

while(i < number_of_nested_lists):
    user_input = int(input())
    data.append(user_input)

    i = i + 1
```

The user inputs three value points at once, in the form:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

and so on. I am unable to convert the input data into int from str, as a ValueError `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3'` The resultant `data` should be `data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`. A newbie in Python, still trying to get lists' concepts clear. I am trying to do it without numpy. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
data.append([int(x) for x in input().split()])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = []
for i in range(x):
    input = raw_input("Enter data point:")
    temp_list = input.split(" ")
    list.append(temp_list)
print list
```

You can use `raw_input`, by default the output will be string. Then simply you split your input string into a `temp_list` (list object).